# Mailer Symfony 6 "550 5.7.1 Sender mismatch"

Tags: symfony, mailer

Ive got a problem with my mailer_DSN configuration (i think).
When i try to send an email i got this message :

```
    Symfony\Component\Mailer\Exception\TransportException: Expected response code "250" but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.1 Sender mismatch"

MAILER_DSN=smtp://MAIL_ADDRESS:PASS@mail.infomaniak.com:465?auth_mode=login
```

Can you help me ?

Regards

Comment: Sounds like the service you use does not allow you to use the given sender address. Did you check this in their documentation?

Comment: Yes, and i found nothing.. Ive tried many things like 465 or 587 SMTPport or differents auth_mode .. And the mailer dsn work great with mailtrap for example

Comment: The error message doesn't mention that you should use another port, or another authorization mode. "Sender mismatch" sounds like you try to use a sender address that the server does not like

Comment: Ok so it's my fault ! I had to configure the from and the to in the controller.. sorry and thx for your reply.